# How to replace an XML element with another (of another document)?

Tags: java, xml, jaxp

Here is my problem:

I have a source XML file that is parsed to a DOM. I also got an XML fragment (like: `<a>text1<b/></a>`). The "root" element of the fragment will always match with an element (same name) in the source DOM. Can I replace the DOM's node with this one?

First, thing I have thought of, is to parse the string fragment as a DOM. Then, I have tried to use `replaceChild()` method, but either I used it incorrectly or it can be applied only for nodes that already exist in the same DOM. So can someone show how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to call getParentNode() first, and then call replaceChild() against the parent node that you've got.

Comment: Thanks, you were right! I have misunderstood the API and tried to applied the method on document root. Now works as expected. Also, I had to use importNode() in order to get a fragment from another document to the desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Importing template node to the target document(this solves wrong_DOCUMENT_ERR:)   
Node importedTemplateChildNode = targetDoc.importNode(templateChildNode, true);

// Replace target child node with the template node
targetParentNode.replaceChild(importedTemplateChildNode, targetChildnode);       

Transformer tranFac = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
tranFac.transform(new DOMSource(targetDoc), new StreamResult(new FileWriter(targetXmlFile)));
```

Comment: Just need to replace 2nd line to below one and it will not throw org.w3c.dom.DOMException  NOT_FOUND_ERR

targetParentNode.getParentNode().replaceChild(importedTemplateChildNode, targetChildnode);

Node nodeToBeReplace = targetDocument.importNode(sourceNode, true);
targetNode.getParentNode().replaceChild(nodeToBeReplace, targetNode);